# Auto resizing of columns width datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

The datatable column are not auto resizing. Here is my code

```
var oTable =$('#test').dataTable( {
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aaData": aDataSet,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "oTableTools": {
        "aButtons": [ {"sExtends": "csv" , "sButtonText": "Save as CSV"}],
        "sSwfPath": "js/jquery/copy_csv_xls.swf"
    },
    "bAutoWidth" : true,
    "sDom": '<"H"lCf>t"H"<"F"iTp>',
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 11 ] }
    ],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "column1" },
        { "sTitle": "column1" },
        { "sTitle": "column1" },
        { "sTitle": "column1"},
        { "sTitle": "column1"},
        { "sTitle": "column1" },
        { "sTitle": "column1" },
        { "sTitle": "column1" },
        { "sTitle": "column1"},
        { "sTitle": "column1 By"},
        { "sTitle": "column1 Date"}
    ]
    } );
oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});
```

I want all the columns to auto resize at least based on their header value.

Answer (score 22):

You just do it like if it was a "normal" `<table>` :

```css
th, td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

see fidle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/YrWG5/** with some extreme long header / content.

Comment: This may no longer work, cause it is not changing anything for me.  Maybe with the latest version of DataTables, it doesn't have an affect on it.

Comment: @CaptainGenesisX, best guess is, if it is not working for you, you have some other CSS overruling. `white-space: nowrap !important;`

Answer (score 4):

Use the below code:

```
   $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
      .columns.adjust();
```

This will resize your table structure (css of the table).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use datatable's `Fluid column width` feature. This will help auto-resize and add a scroll both on the `X` and `Y` axis should you have more columns to display

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        columnDefs: [
            { width: '20%', targets: 0 }
        ],
        fixedColumns: true
    } );
} );
```

Gotten from [HERE](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/size_fluid.html)

Answer (score 1):

Put this code after data table initialization:

```
oTable.find('thead th').css('width', 'auto');
```